# Linux "mv" command, created a new file (when no folder is available)

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ubuntu

I am using Mac terminal, inside using linux commands to find list of ".jpg" files and try to move to "myimages" folder in current directory with below command.

`find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mv {} myimages \;`

At the time of executing above command I don't have a folder named "myimages" .

Now all my .jpg files are disappeared and there is a new file "myimages" is created in the current directory.

i guess all my images are converted into single file with name "myimages".

how to get back all images back from "myimgages" file?

Please help me.

Comment: This is what you get when you run "linux commands" on a "Mac terminal" ...

Comment: @janos what do you mean? Mac OS runs a Unix under the hood; basic commands are going to be mostly identical to modern-day Linux distros. No?

Comment: How large is the `myimages` file? My guess is it's renamed every file to `myimages`, and what you're seeing is simply the last one in the row. In which case there is unlikely to be a way to revert the change I'm afraif.

Comment: @Pekka it was a joke. Since you asked: "UNIX commands" would have been closer, "BSD commands" even better. Linux is not even an operating system. What are "linux commands"? Kernel method calls? "Linux mv command" on UNIX/BSD? That's so inappropriate it's bordering on insult. The most correct way would have been to not label the commands: *"Running `find` and `mv` commands on my Mac to move a bunch of files, things went awfully wrong..."* And what's the `ubuntu` tag doing there?

Answer (score 2):

Your images are gone. Each image gets moved to the file `myimages`, effectively overwriting the existing file. You can try with recovery software to get them back.

In the future, use the command `find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mv {} myimages/ \;` instead (note the trailing slash). You can also provide the `-i` flag to `mv`, so it prompts before overwriting existing files.

Answer (score 2):

Your photos are gone. Your command renamed all of them, one by one, to `myimages`.

You can:

1. Try to recover from backups
2. Try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), an image recovery tool
3. Try [Exif Untrasher](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/exif-untrasher/), an image recovery tool
4. Try some other image recovery tool

Btw, you cannot run "linux commands" on a Mac. On a Mac you are running Mac commands (compiled for Mac OS X), or shell scripts. Also the `ubuntu` tag didn't make any sense for your question.

In the future you can avoid such mistakes by putting a trailing slash at the end of the destination if it's supposed to be a directory:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mv {} myimages/ \;
```

This way you would get an error message saying:

> mv: rename blah to myimages/: No such file or directory

and nothing would be moved, and you would still have your fields.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get back all images back from "myimgages" file?

You can't.  Since the target directory `myimages` did not exist, every output from `find` resulted in something like:

```
mv ./file1.jpg myimages
mv ./file2.jpg myimages
...
```

In each of these commands, the target was `myimages`.  Since it didn't exist as a directory, `mv` assumed that it was the target filename.

---

You could fix the command by saying:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mv -t myimages {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Restore them from backup.

The commands you executed are

```
mv file1 myimages # rename file
mv file2 myimages # rename file, discarding the old file previously referred to by myimages
```

and so on.

Besides the trailing slash [mentioned by knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728218/296974), I'd recommend for the next time to use

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mv -t myimages/ {} +
```

which clearly states "doubly" that `myimages` is the target directory and which allows for multiple files to be moved at one `mv` execution.